# How can I create a new RoleDefinition in powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, sharepoint-online

I need to create a new RoleDefinition and apply it to a group.
Is that possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is possible.
You need to use CSOM. Look at this example:

```
Write-Host "Opening $tenancySiteCollectionUrl ... " -NoNewLine
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($tenancySiteCollectionUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $securePassword)

$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web)

Write-Host "OK" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black

Write-Host "Creating the 'Contribute - No Deletion' RoleDefinition ... " -NoNewLine
$permissions = New-Object "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.BasePermissions"
$permissions.Set([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::AddListItems)
$permissions.Set([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::ViewListItems)
$permissions.Set([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::EditListItems)

$roleDefinitionCreationInfo = New-Object "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionCreationInformation"
$roleDefinitionCreationInfo.Name = "$roleDefinitionName"
$roleDefinitionCreationInfo.Description = "Can view, add, and update list items and documents"
$roleDefinitionCreationInfo.BasePermissions = $permissions
$web.RoleDefinitions.Add($roleDefinitionCreationInfo)

Try
{
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "Done" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    Write-Error $ex
    break
}
```

Then you need to modify your existing group in this way:

```
    New-SPOSiteGroup "$($tenancySiteCollectionUrl)" -Group "$($groupName)" -PermissionLevels "Contribute"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the powershell to create the same thing

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://dmg-10
$permname = "PermName1"



#create role def
$roledef = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleDefinition
$roledef.BasePermissions = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::FullMask -bxor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::ManageSubwebs
#[enum]::GetValues([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRights]) | ?{$_.value__ -band $roledef.BasePermissions}

$roledef.Name = $permname
$web.RoleDefinitions.Add($roledef)
$web.Update()

#remove other role assignments (ie. Full Control)
$web.RoleAssignments.Remove($web.AssociatedOwnerGroup)
$web.AssociatedOwnerGroup.Update()
$web.Update()

#assign role def to group
$roledef = $web.RoleDefinitions[$permname]
$roleassign = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($web.AssociatedOwnerGroup)
$roleassign.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roledef);
$web.RoleAssignments.Add($roleassign)
$web.AssociatedOwnerGroup.Update()
$web.Update()
```

Source: http://www.gbois.com/view/5/PowerShell-SharePoint-Creating-Role-Definition-and-Applying-to-a-Group

Comment: does that work on SP Online?

Comment: @Gaetanu no that would'nt work on SP Online. You need to use CSOM in conjunction with PowerShell SP Online cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

[New-SPOPermissionLevel](https://sharepointonlineautomationcmdlets.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=New-SPOPermissionLevel&referringTitle=Documentation)

To create the RoleDefinition and [New-SPOGroup](https://sharepointonlineautomationcmdlets.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=New-SPOGroup)
if you want to create a group with that RoleDefinition.